# Duplicate Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have created one asp.net page and i am trying to bind data to gridview but its showing duplicate gridview downside of my original gridview how to remove that duplicate gridview please help me

[This is my page's screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhwvS.png)

this is my Code Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        GridBind();
    }      
}
public void GridBind()
{
    int Year = DateTime.Now.Year;
    int Month = DateTime.Now.Month;
    int curMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(Year, Month);
    DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter Adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select Distinct e.EmpId,e.FirstName,e.Designation, count(a.status) as 'Present Days' ,('" + curMonth + "'-count(a.status)) as 'Absent Days','" + curMonth + "' as'Total Days' from EmployeeMaster e , attendance a where a.status='Absent' and e.EmployeeId=a.EmployeeId  group by e.EmpId,e.firstName,e.Designation", sqlcon);       
    Adp.Fill(Dt);
    gvattendance.DataSource = Dt;
    gvattendance.DataBind();
}
```

}

Comment: Does it show one the first time, 2 the second etc? as although your code here doesnt show it it would suggest that would be the behavior

Comment: Is this inside a user control?

Comment: no @BugFinder from first postback its showing two gridview

Comment: Just by itself this code cannot produce the situation in the screenshot. The problem is elsewhere. Try to include enough code to reproduce the issue. By doing that experiment to find what to include, you may end up finding the problem by yourself.

Comment: Are you making a copy of the html with javascript somewhere? Because as @ADyson says, the GridView is asexual and cannot reproduce by itself.

Comment: @VDWWD sexuality of code...there's a novel PHD project lol

Comment: i got solution it was viewstate problem actually i was using gridview inside update panel so after changing viewstate property of update panel False its working fine